# How do I add to the row of a specific string in a .txt file in Python?

Tags: python, text-files

With the function `appendA ()` I want to be a able to search for the variable `crop` and then append the variable `quantity` onto the end of the same row as `crop`. As I am relatively new to Python I'm not sure how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
crop = input("Which crop? ")
quantity = input("How many? ")

def appendA ():
 file.write (quantity + ' ')

def appendB ():
 file.write ('\n')
 file.write (crop + ' ')
 file.write (quantity + ' ')

with open ('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+') as file:
 if crop in open('cropdatabase.txt').read():
    appendA ()
 else:
    appendB ()

file.close ()
```

Comment: Read the file into a list of lines. Append to the line affected. Write the lines.

Comment: in your `appendA()`, when you are writing the file, you are making a new file that holds `quantity `.

Comment: You should ask a specific question in the context of your code, so people know where you are stuck. There are a few problems with your code (for instance, `appendA` just appends the quantity, hoping against all hope that it will be done in the right place), but you should start at how you open `file` but don't pass it to the `append` functions, so it doesn't exist there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's load the file into something nicer to work with such as a list:

```
lines = file.readlines()
```

Now let's find our crop and add quantity to it:

```
index = lines.index(crop)
lines[index] += ' ' + str(quantity)
```

At last save the file:

```
open(file_path, 'w').write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Comment: `index` will only find the crop if there is no quantity, which won't be the case. You'd have to split the lines and match the `crop` to the first element.

Comment: Yes, I get 'ValueError: '(whichever string is contained within crop)' is not in list'. When you say "split the lines and match crop to the first element', what do you mean?

Comment: Hammer split the file into lines. Then you have to split each line into crop and quantity and compare the first element of that split with your crop, to see if it's already there.